# How to I can exclude the button function from the highlight selected rows on the css style of "TR"?

Tags: css, google-apps-script, google-sheets, stylesheet, spreadsheet

Hy, Guess. I have the pieces line of the codes the bit of mine I will show you. I'll hope you'll be give me the right answer. **Firstly** I have the **CSS code** where the structure of lines has being looks like this :

```
<style type='text/css'>
.gridview {
    display: inline-block;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0px 4px 4px 0;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #bbb;
}

.gridview, .gridview td {
    margin: 0;
    border:  1px solid #cccccc;
}

.gridview tr {
    background: #F4F9FD;
}

.gridview tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #EDF5FC;
}

.gridview tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #F4F9FD;
}

.gridview td {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.gridview td {
    padding: 4px 10px 5px 9px;
}

.gridview tr:hover td, .gridview tbody tr:hover td {
    background-color: #feb4cc;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
}

.gridview .selected, .gridview tbody .selected {
    background-color: #E74C3C;
    color: #fff;
}

button {
    display: none;
}

td:hover button {
    display: block;
    margin: -1px -8px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 2px 0px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
}
</style>
```

the **Secondly** I have a litle bit the **JavaScript** such as like this :

```
function highlight(e) {
  if (e.className == 'selected') {
    e.className = e.className.replace('selected', '');}
      else {
        e.className += 'selected';
    }
}

function toClipboard(e) {
  var cell = e.parentNode,
      copyText = cell.getElementsByTagName('span'),
      selection = window.getSelection(),
      range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(copyText[0]);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
    document.execCommand('copy');
}
</script>
```

And the finally the **Thirdly** of the **HTML** content see at the down below this :

```
<table border=1 class='gridview'>
    <colgroup>
        <col width='135'/>
        <col width='130'/>
        <col width='250'/>
    </colgroup>

        <tr OnClick=highlight(this)>
            <td><span>Row 1 Column 1 of Loren Ipsum</span><button onclick=toClipboard(this)><small>Copy</small></button></td>
            <td><span>Row 1 Column 2 of Loren Ipsum</span><button onclick=toClipboard(this)><small>Copy</small></button></td>
            <td><span>Row 1 Column 3 of Loren Ipsum</span><button onclick=toClipboard(this)><small>Copy</small></button></td>
        </tr>

        <tr OnClick=highlight(this)>
            <td><span>Row 2 Column 1 of Loren Ipsum</span><button onclick=toClipboard(this)><small>Copy</small></button></td>
            <td><span>Row 2 Column 2 of Loren Ipsum</span><button onclick=toClipboard(this)><small>Copy</small></button></td>
            <td><span>Row 2 Column 3 of Loren Ipsum</span><button onclick=toClipboard(this)><small>Copy</small></button></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

***The Problems is*** *How to if I don't want to including the Highlighting selected rows when I clicked the button of **toClipboard()** function running at the same time ???*

> Anyway thanks in advance was taken of your time to read this tread and
>   any help will be appreciate thanks one more time and sorry about my
>   poor english ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) at the end of your `toClipboard()` function to prevent "further propagation of the current event".

```
function toClipboard(e) {
  var cell = e.parentNode,
      copyText = cell.getElementsByTagName('span'),
      selection = window.getSelection(),
      range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(copyText[0]);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
    document.execCommand('copy');
    event.stopPropagation(); // This prevents highlight(e) from being called
}
```

Comment: Wow it's wonderful works perfectly. Thanks, it through works nice directly !!!